# Unable to find projects on edgeSDK Oauth Tool

Tags: macos, edgesdk, edgeengine

I installed mimik edgeservice and edgeSDK OAuth Tool. The edgeservice is up and learning. From the developer console, when I create a new project and open the OAuth Tool, it shows the following message:
Oops! Can't find any projects, please connect from mimik developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can open OAuth Tool from applications. This ensures that the installation was successful. If OAuth Tool opens you can login to your developer account from there. If it does not open then you may need to allow the application to open by going to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General and allow OAuth Tool to open.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed a new version: OAuth tool 1.1.0 and it works.